# Como crear huella digital asociada a la app de producción

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin

Tengo problemas con el login de Google, si instalo la aplicación desde Android Studio inicia sesión  sin problemas, pero en cuanto subo el app bundle a la consola de Google Play en prueba interna, instalo esa versión subida e intento iniciar la sesión con Google, no funciona.

He estado buscando y llegado a la conclusión de que tengo que crear una huella digital asociada a la app de producción. Ya tengo la dicha huella, ¿Pero qué es lo que tengo que hacer con ella ahora? No encuentro más información al respecto, la he agregado a Firebase pero el problema persiste. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Adjunto capturas del problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la huella generada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edit:

Una vez hecho lo que comenta Jorge se me solicita la siguiente información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No dispongo de dominio, si introduzco el creado en Android Studio com.silentappstudio."nombre de la apk" me lleva a otra pantalla en la que verificar un dominio introduciendo su dns que obviamente no dispongo. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme por favor?

Comment: Morodo, estas usando Google Sign-In verdad?

Comment: Buenas Jorge, efectivamente.

Comment: revisa mi respuesta, es importante que desde la consola asignes permisos para el SHA-1 del certificado con el que firmas tu aplicación a Google Play.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Jorge, he hecho lo que comentas. Por lo visto tardan entre 4 a 6 semanas en verificar la aplicación. Volveré a comentar si tengo algún problema.

Comment: Hola Morodo, excelentes. Sabes actualmente pueden tardar varias semanas si es una nueva aplicaciòn pero si es una actualizaciòn tarda menos de una semana, saludos.

Comment: Buenas Jorge, parece que hay algún problema añadido, puedes echarme una mano? He editado mi pregunta con la nueva información. Gracias!

Comment: Buen día, @Morodo como se llama específicamente la api que estas usando ?, estas usando una API Key o un ID de cliente ? es en uno de estos donde debes de registrar el SHA-1

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas estas usando una o varias APIs de Google.

[Google Sign-in o Google Identity](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android)

pero el problema que comentas:

> si instalo la aplicación desde Android Studio inicia sesión sin
> problemas, pero en cuanto subo el app bunddle a la consola de Google
> Play en prueba interna

**El problema se debe a que al subir la aplicaciòn (.APK o .AAB) desde Android Studio esta se firma automàticamente con un certificado de debug, y el `SHA-1` de este certificado tiene permisos para usar la API pero al firmar tu aplicaciòn para subir a `Google Play` usas otro certificado.**

Debes obtener el `SHA-1` del certificado con el que firmas la app para Google Play, que al parecer es el que muestras en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asignarle permisos para uso de la API, revisa:

[Configure su proyecto de consola de API de Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started#api-console)

El punto 3 indica especificar el package name y el `SHA-1`:

> 1. Abra su proyecto en la consola de API , o crear un proyecto si no tiene ya uno.
> 2. En la página de la pantalla de consentimiento de OAuth, asegúrese de que toda la información esté completa y sea precisa. En particular,
>    asegúrese de haber especificado las URL de la política de privacidad y
>    los términos de servicio de su aplicación.
> 3. **En la página Credenciales, cree un ID de cliente de Android para su aplicación si aún no tiene uno. Deberá especificar el nombre del
>    paquete de su aplicación y la firma SHA-1**.
> 4. En la página Credenciales, cree un ID de cliente de aplicación web si aún no tiene uno. Puede dejar en blanco los campos Authorized
>    JavaScript Origins y Authorized redirect URIs. Este ID de cliente
>    representa su servidor backend de autenticación. (Utilizaría este ID
>    de cliente cuando llame a las API de Google desde su servidor, pero lo
>    necesitará incluso si no lo hace).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]